# RegEx pattern that must always match two tokens

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following string:

```
"\Myfile.png"
```

I am trying to write a RegEx pattern, that must always match the `\` and `.` characters, if both characters are not present in the string, there should not be a match at all.
I need this for PowerShell, I have tried the following:

```
"\MyFile.png" -Match "\\|\."
```

But it always returns `$True`. I need it to be `$True` only if both `\` and `.` are present.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your use `|` which is an logical OR, so it matches when a `\` and/ or `.` are present. If you remove `|` and instead add that there can be zero or more characters (any characters, but can be detailed if required) in between those two, then you get what you want. The resulting pattern would then be `\\.*\.`.

```
"\Myfile.png" -match "\\.*\." # True
"\Myfile.something.png" -match "\\.*\." # True
"\MyFolder\AnotherFolder\MyFile.something.png" -match "\\.*\." # True
"\MyFolder\MyFile.something.png" -match "\\.*\." # True

"\Myfilepng" -match "\\.*\." # False
"Myfile.png" -match "\\.*\." # False
```